# HTML5 markup for content-related marginalia

Tags: html, semantics, markup

I'm looking for a proper way to add HTML5 (semantic) content-related [marginalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginalia) (like images, notes, amendments, lists,...) to the text of an article (which means inside of `<article>` within `<p>`).

My first though was to use `<aside>` but on the [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Main_Page) I found this:

> The `<aside>` element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, and which could be considered separate from that content. (via [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/aside))

...even though marginalia is not indirect (like copyright) but **direct related** (like amendments) to the content, the aside tag seems to be a suitable option but only as a [sections-tag](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements#Sections) instead of [text-level semantics](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements#Text-level_semantics). The markup would result in something like this:

```
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <aside>(dolor euismod tincidunt)</aside>
</article>
```

Instead of this:

```
<article>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor <span>(dolor euismod tincidunt)</span> sit amet.</p>
</article>
```

---

On text-level layer there are possibly `<small>` and/or `<mark>` (instead of `<span>` above):

> The `<small>` element represents side comments such as small print. (via [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/small))

...which could be used for attribution but is made for small print (like copyrights).

> The `<mark>` element represents a run of text in one document marked or
>   highlighted for reference purposes, due to its relevance in another
>   context. (via [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/mark))

...which could be used for reference purposes in another additional context (like single search keywords).

---

To sum it up: I'm looking for a proper way to add additional (related) content after a specific word within a text. How would I achieve this semantically? Are there any more suitable (HTML5) tags or even other options to do this?

A possible use case could be a misspelled word in a text, with the right spelling added as marginalia with additional information about the evolutionary history of the affected word.

Comment: In addition to being primarily opinion-based (HTML5 “semantics” is mostly play with words, and different people play it differently), it is very abstract (no real cases were presented), and the choice of markup has no impact, apart from the obvious (some elements have different default rendering).

Comment: Thanks, I added a possible use case at the end of my question. So the markup doesn't matter? Not even for search engines?

Comment: The example is concrete, but rather specialized. By HTML5 principles, you could use `u` or `mark` for the misspelled word itself and `aside` for the content that has the correct spelling and some explanations. But there is really no solid ground, no real definitions of *meanings* that would e.g. let you decide between `u` and `mark`, or to decide whether to use `aside` or not. And what *could* the markup matter? There is much speculation of what searche engines *might* do with it, and no evidence of their actually doing something.

Answer (score 0):

`<dfn>` would be a solution for text terms.

Comment: The question did not mention terms at all.